# How to downgrade Rack to 2.0.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, ruby-grape

I am using Administrate in my rails app, it is upgraded from 0.9.0 to 0.15.0 version. After that `rack` is upgraded to 2.2.3 as following.
I also using grape and wine_bouncer with Doorkeeper for authorization.
`wine_bouncer` requires **Grape > 0.10 and < 1.2**
Due to [this](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/issues/1966) incompatible version issue, I want to keep my rack version as 2.0.8 and grape is 1.2.5. How can I force rack down to 2.0.8? I don't see rack in gemfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to Gemfile `gem 'rack', '= 2.0.8'` and after run `bundle` command. Now rack version is 2.0.8